# eslint don't see bound context

Tags: javascript, eslint

```
import {resizeHandler} from '@/components/table/table.resize'
...
const $resizer = $(event.target)
console.log('sentContext:', this)
resizeHandler.bind(this, $resizer)()


// Exported function
export function resizeHandler($resizer) {
    ...    
    console.log('receivedContext:', this)
}
```

From another class I call func "resizeHandler". I pass needed context and it works as expected:

[image: works]

Can please someone explain why eslint raging about 'invalid' this. Eslint doc [says](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-invalid-this) that "The call/apply/bind method of the function is called directly". Is it not my case? Should it not see passed context.

[image]

Comment: Maybe because “normal” functions are not expected to use `this`. You can disable that rule if you think it shouldn’t apply to this function.

Comment: @FelixKling it's not normal to use bind? Well, ok. Yea I know I can turn off the rule. Just curious.

Comment: I'm not saying it's not normal. Just that using `this` is unexpected by just looking at the function. You can do whatever you want as long as you know what you are doing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `call/apply/bind method` is not being called directly in the code you posted. More generally, `this` is necessary only if you expect state to persist. Your function gets called once and then it is done; no object is persisted for later reference. Thus, `this` is unnecessary.